# How do I make an axios request in a Vue component from a route made using an Adonis controller

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex, adonis.js

I have a `WidgetController.js` file that performs CRUD operations on the database. This controller has a `* create (request, response)` method/generator that basically returns a response containing the widget attributes and also adds a row to the database `widgets` table. The route is defined as `Route.any('widgets/create', 'WidgetController.create').as('widgets.create').middleware('auth');`. I want `create` to be triggered by a click of a button on the frontend, and I tried the normal import in Vue:

```
<template>
    <div> 
        <button @click="createWidget">Click me</button>
    </div>
</template>
<style></style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    import WidgetController from '/path/to/WidgetController.js';
    export default{
        name: 'widget',
        data () {
            return{
                WidgetCtrl: WidgetController                
            }
        },
        methods: {
            createWidget () {
                return this.WidgetCtrl.create();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

but it doesn't work probably because of dependencies and functions that are exclusive to Adonis and not defined in Vue. I learned that `axios` may be able to do what I want. How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import or access server side's js file from the client side.
As you're trying to import adonis's WidgetController.js from vue.js

You've to make HTTP request in 'createWidget' function and point it to WidgetController.create method.

Vue's component file:

```
<template>
    <div> 
        <button @click="createWidget">Click me</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">

    export default{
        name: 'widget',
        data () {
            return{
                WidgetCtrl: WidgetController                
            }
        },
        methods: {
            createWidget () {
                axios.get('/url-point-to-WidgetController.create')
                     .then(response => {
                         // do other stuff
                      });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Adonis's WidgetController.js:

```
'use strict'

class WidgetController {

    * create(request, response) {
       // save widget...
    }

}

module.exports = WidgetController
```